# Create a form and insert the data into database using $wpdb

Tags: php, database, wordpress, forms, themes

I have a custom WordPress page template where I wrote a basic form structure like this:

```
<div class="my-form">
    <h2>WILL YOU ATTEND?</h2>
    <form action="#" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
        <input class="input" type="text" spellcheck="false" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input class="input" type="email" spellcheck="false" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

        <label class="ans">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="radio">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="ans">No
            <input type="radio" name="radio">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <button> SUBMIT </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Now once the submit button is clicked, I'm trying to figure out how to create a table in WordPress database, and insert the form data into it using `$wpdb`.

PS: I left the `action` attribute empty because I don't know how to go about this exactly.

Comment: In which table do you want to add your form data? If you want to add data to your custom table then you've to create that first.

Comment: @AkhtarujjamanShuvo alright, I've manually created a table called 'customform'. So I want to add the data into this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Below I just showed you one way:

I Assume your table name is wp_customform which has **id**, **name**, **email**, and **radio** columns.

Now you've to modify your HTML code like the below. I added some JS too.

```
<div class="my-form">
    <h2>WILL YOU ATTEND?</h2>
    <form class="custom-form-class" action="#" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

        <!-- Action is here but hidden. This will be use in php side -->
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sample_custom_form_action">

        <input class="input" type="text" spellcheck="false" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input class="input" type="email" spellcheck="false" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

        <label class="ans">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="radio">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="ans">No
            <input type="radio" name="radio">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <button> SUBMIT </button>
   </form>
</div>


<script>

    // Javascript to send ajax request
    jQuery(document).on('submit', '.custom-form-class', function(e){
        let formData = jQuery(this).serialize();

        // Change ajax url value to your domain
        let ajaxurl = 'http://YOURSITE.COM/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

        // Send ajax
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, formData, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

That pieces of code will send your form data to the PHP side. You have to use the below code to process the form data in your function.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sample_custom_form_action', 'prefix_save_custom_form_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sample_custom_form_action', 'prefix_save_custom_form_data' );
function prefix_save_custom_form_data(){
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Get the values
    $name  = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name'] ) : ''; // Empty value if data not set
    $email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ) : ''; // Empty value if data not set
    $radio = isset( $_POST['radio'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['radio'] ) : ''; // Empty value if data not set

    // Assume your table name is wp_customform
    $your_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'customform';

    // Insert into database
    $wpdb->insert(
        $your_table_name, 
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'radio' => $radio,
        )
    );

    // Send insert id as ajax response
    echo $wpdb->insert_id;

    // Use die to stop the ajax action
    wp_die();
}
```

The codes are not tested but they should work. I am attaching some reference links below:

Ajax overview: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

For Insert: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/

For create table: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

Comment: You might consider using a nonce check in your php Ajax action. Also your  'data' in the ajax post is undefined, as well as the 'action'

Comment: @HowardE thanks for pointing out the `data` variable. I updated the code.